# Trying to identify part driving in magnetic levitator. Maybe a 2.5 V switching regulator?

Tags: voltage-regulator, electromagnetism, identification, reverse-engineering

Its from a toy magnetic levitator purchased on alibaba. I wanted to understand and modify it but the key component has the markings sanded off. I'm pretty sure I got the pins figured out and know how it works but I would love to find the actual part.

See the images below. The chip is a SOIC8 I believe and it provides an ~450 kHz PWM signal to drive the control coils at ~1 A. The PWM seems to be ~(50% + 100*(2.5-Feedback)) with the 100 number being a really rough estimate.

Anyone got any ideas? I would be really grateful.

[image: What I have figured out]

[image: image on the board]

Comment: Could just be an mcu

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that's pretty unlikely since it is driving ~1 A. There are also 2 of them. I was assuming it would be cheaper to just use one.

Comment: If there aren't any markings then your odds of finding out what it is are slim

Comment: Yeah, I thought that might be the case but I was hoping someone would either have new suggestions of things to search or, if I was lucky, recognize the pinout.